# How use .load()

Tags: jquery, url, load

I have problem with jquery. I have use include('somefile.php') in my script

But when i want load this somefile.php from jquery not working.

Here my php script

```
<tr>
    <td width="35%" valign="top"><?php include('inputform.php');?></td>
    <td width="64%" id="listTbl"><div id="List"><?php include('somefile.php');?></div></td>
</tr>
```

And here my jquery script

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'savedata.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
                  $("imgLoad").show();
               },
    complete: function() {
                $("imgLoad").hide();
             },        
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
            $("#cText1").val('');       
            $('#imgLoad').hide();
            $('.button_blue').attr("disabled", false);      
            $('#msgConfirm').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
            $("#msgConfirm").html(' Save Success.');
            $("#cText1").focus();
            $('#listTbl').load("listcategory.php #List >*",function(){
               //after loading completion code goes here                      
            });
        }
        return false;       
    });
```

This jquery script have nothing load. Page just blank. But i try different way like below

```
$('#catListTbl').load("listcategory.php");
```

and i've try this one too

```
$('#catListTbl').load("listcategory.php");
```

But 2 of above short script let me in got error. Error about database cannot be open, table not found, all sql command will be error like below.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 9

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 11

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 11

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 12

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\includes\opentable.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\somefile.php on line 44

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\somefile.php on line 44

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Webserver\Apache2\htdocs\Listing\somefile.php on line 45
```

Please give me advise for this problem or any solution. Thank's

Comment: Start at the top of your list and fix this basic error: "Access Denied" means you have used the wrong user ID or password or both. Fix that, try again. Repeat until you don't have errors. This is very basic stuff.

Comment: i'm not using password at mysql, and if i'm load without jquery all work fine. What i'm trying is reload this "somefile.php" without load full page.